# SQL insert all of a column into a table with second column constant

Tags: sql

I have a new table, which consists of two columns. What I am trying to do is insert all of the values from one column in another table into the new table, but have the second column be constant.

For example:

```
Table1 
ID
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

```
New Table
COL1   COL2
1       1
2       1
3       1
4       1
5       1
6       1
7       1
```

I am trying to insert all of the ids from table 1 to COL1 from the new table, while having COL2 be some constant
How would I achieve this?

Comment: `INSERT INTO table2
SELECT Col1, 1 as col2 FROM table1` Try this

Comment: Define the column as default constant. create table so_56( col1 number, col2 number default 1); insert into so_56 (col1)select id from table1;

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I haved solved this issue using @JaydipJadhavs solution, but since he posted it as a comment I am not sure how to accept it

Answer (score 1):

You can use a constant in a SELECT statement:

```
INSERT INTO
  NewTable
(
    Col1
  , Col2
)
SELECT
    Id AS Col1
  , 1 AS Col2
FROM
  Table1;
```

Or if you wish to use a pre-assigned variable you can write:

```
DECLARE @Col2Value AS INT;
SET @Col2Value = 1;

INSERT INTO
  NewTable
(
    Col1
  , Col2    )
SELECT
    Id AS Col1
  , @Col2Value AS Col2

FROM
  Table1;
```

If you want the new table to have a default value for the second column, you could define this in the table declaration, then insert only the values for the first column:

```
CREATE TABLE
(
    Col1 INT
  , Col2 INT DEFAULT(1)
);

INSERT INTO
  NewTable
(
  Col1
)
SELECT
   Id AS Col1
FROM
  Table1;
```

Answer (score -1):

If `table2` exists, you can do:

```
insert into table2 (col1, col2)
    select col1, 1
    from table1;
```

If `table2` does *not* exist and you want to create it, then there is syntax for that.  The most common is `create table as`:

```
create table table2 as
    select col1, 1 as col2
    from table1;
```

Some databases use the `into` syntax:

```
select col1, 1 as col2
into table2
from table1;
```