# need to insert data from SQL table 1 table 2 but one column data is constant

Tags: mysql

I need to insert data in table 2 but it has a column 3 which is a constant. How to built query for this comdition

?
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, **column3**)
SELECT column1, column2
FROM table1
?

Comment: Does this answer of your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58342587/sql-insert-all-of-a-column-into-a-table-with-second-column-constant

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL insert all of a column into a table with second column constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58342587/sql-insert-all-of-a-column-into-a-table-with-second-column-constant)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add your constant value after `column2` from the `select`

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3) 
SELECT column1, column2, 'your constant value'
FROM table1
```